# Arduino LCD doesn't work properly after +-24hours

Tags: arduino

Everything works just fine, but after about 24hours the display only lights up, but doesn't display any text. Any suggestions please ? Im resseting the tx variable with button press, and it is of type `unsigned long tx;`

```
if(digitalRead(6) == LOW && millis()-pressed >= 1000){
    tx = millis();
}

if (millis() - tx < 60000) {                                            
    // LCD displays stops every 10 minutes 
    // (600000 milli seconds) (1 minute 60000 mili seconds)
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Temp: " + String(temperature));
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("T1: " + String(t1) + " H T2: " + String(t2) + " M");
    digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT,HIGH);
}
else
{
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT,LOW);                                          
    //Nodata on display
}
```

Comment: Do you change your TX variable anywhere else? Otherwise, we can probably eliminate millis flowing over as a reason (which happens around every 50 days, according to the arduino documentation: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/ )

Comment: Yeah but this bug happens after around 24hours, no it's not being changed anywhere else

Comment: I can't see any other relevant problems from the part of the code you posted. Maybe add a minimal but complete version of your sketch, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works just fine, turns out that the ground cable was poorly attached.